# Automatically set Store Generated Pattern to Computed when generating from database

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-database-first

Is there anyway to have a properties `StoreGeneratedPattern` automatically set to `Computed` in ADO.net when generated from a database where the fields default value or binding is set?

Is this also possible with fields that have triggers?